# Is it possible to create a room in Firebase?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, server

I wanna create an app which doesn't have any login screen. One of the users will create a room and the others will join in the room via ID and Password or maybe kind of barcode system I don't know. Can I do that and do you have any suggest to do this login system?

Btw I'm using Swift

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: What you mean by Room ? are you working on webrtc projects?

Comment: I mean like Zoom application. Users come together in a room and shared posts to eachother. It’s my school project. For example I created a room and shared room’s ID and Password. Then my friends will join the room via ID and Password. I shared a post and my friends can see the post or someone shared a post I can see too in table view.

Comment: Refer the answer below : ---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to your question. The think you finding for your school projects will be the thing call `webrtc` reference ~> https://webrtc.org/ (an Open source project) which just fit what you been doing , and `Twillio` reference ~> https://www.twilio.com/ if you want be fast without coding from scratch.

My answer to your question is ***YES***

You can always learn from here [THE TUTORIAL](https://www.sitepoint.com/real-time-video-chat-room/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my homework is like chat application. One person created a room and others joined inside. Then one of them share a text like ‘Hello’ and other users in the room can see ‘hello’ text in table view. I’m using xcode. Thanks for your answer again :)

Comment: Specifically is like what ?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally pressed the enter button when I’m writing :D I edited my aswer

Comment: It Is possible. Just keep googling for 'webrtc swift'

Comment: @baypilot This answer doesn't appear to have anything to do with creating a room IN FIREBASE or SWIFT. It's good info but unrelated to the question. You will need to learn about Javascript and adapters to implement this solution - just be aware it's not Swift.

Comment: @Jay I think you missing the point that he wanted to create a clone like zoom. Same, not just can be used in JavaScript, as he wanted to do it in swift for iOS.

Comment: No, I got it. Here's the question **Is it possible to create a room in Firebase?** followed by **Btw I'm using Swift** neither of which the answer addresses. As mentioned, its good general info but for future readers searching specifically for help with *code* (this is a coding forum) that will enable them to create a room in Firebase using Swift, this answer won't help them with a coding solution.